# Having problems with searchbar logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I'm a beginner and I'm trying to build a simple phonebook, where you can add persons and filter them with their name.

My problem is, that when I'm trying to add a new contact, the new contact does't show until I write something in the searchbar.
When I deleted the search component, I was able to add contacts normally.

Here is my code so far:
(App.js)

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import Person from './components/Person'


const App = () => {

  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
    { name: 'Arto Hellas', number: '040-123456', id: 1 },
    { name: 'Ada Lovelace', number: '39-44-5323523', id: 2 },
    { name: 'Dan Abramov', number: '12-43-234345', id: 3 },
    { name: 'Mary Poppendieck', number: '39-23-6423122', id: 4 }
  ])

  const [newName, setNewName] = useState('')
  const [newNumber, setNewNumber] = useState('')
  const[newSearch, setNewSearch] = useState('')
  const[personsFilter, setPersonsFilter] = useState(persons)

  const addContact = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const nameObject = {
      name: newName,
      number: newNumber,
      id: persons.length+1,
    }

  const currentPerson = persons.filter((person) => person.name === newName);
      if (currentPerson.length === 1) {
        alert(`${newName} is already added to phonebook`)
      } else {
      setPersons(persons.concat(nameObject))
      setNewName('')
      setNewNumber('')
    }
  }

  const handleNameChange = (event) => {
    setNewName(event.target.value)
  }

  const handleNumberChange = (event) => {
    setNewNumber(event.target.value)
  }
  
  const filterPersons = (event) => {
    const searchName = event.target.value.toLowerCase()
    setNewSearch(searchName)
    const newPersons = persons.filter (
      (person) => 
        person.name.toLowerCase().search(searchName) !== -1
    )
    setPersonsFilter(newPersons)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <div>
        filter:
        <input value={newSearch}
               onChange={filterPersons}
        />
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={addContact}>
        <div>
          name: <input 
                  value={newName}
                  onChange={handleNameChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          number: <input
                  value={newNumber}
                  onChange={handleNumberChange}/>
          </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
      <ul>
          <Person persons={personsFilter} /> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

(Persons.js)

```
import React from "react";

const Person = ({ persons }) => {
    return persons.map((person) => 
        <li key={person.id}>{person.name}: <span>{person.number}</span></li>
    )
}
  
  export default Person
```

and index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

I hope I explained my error clearly lol
Thanks in advance
Have great day <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is when you set a new person it only updates the `persons` state not the `personsFilter` state. The `personsFilter` state is the one being used to show data to the DOM. The reason it works when you filter is because your function `filterPersons()` takes a copy of the `persons`  state.

Instead of focusing on two states why not just use a single `searchTerm` state then just filter that when you map?

This is how I would do it:

App.js

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import Person from './components/Person'

const App = () => {

  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
    { name: 'Arto Hellas', number: '040-123456', id: 1 },
    { name: 'Ada Lovelace', number: '39-44-5323523', id: 2 },
    { name: 'Dan Abramov', number: '12-43-234345', id: 3 },
    { name: 'Mary Poppendieck', number: '39-23-6423122', id: 4 }
  ])

  const [newName, setNewName] = useState('')
  const [newNumber, setNewNumber] = useState('')
  const[searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')

  const addContact = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const nameObject = {
      name: newName,
      number: newNumber,
      id: persons.length+1,
    }

  const currentPerson = persons.filter((person) => person.name === newName);
      if (currentPerson.length === 1) {
        alert(`${newName} is already added to phonebook`)
      } else {
      setPersons(persons.concat(nameObject))
      setNewName('')
      setNewNumber('')
    }
  }

  const handleNameChange = (event) => {
    setNewName(event.target.value)
  }

  const handleNumberChange = (event) => {
    setNewNumber(event.target.value)
  }
  
  const filterPersons = (event) => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Phonebook</h2>
      <div>
        filter:
        <input value={searchTerm}
               onChange={filterPersons}
        />
      </div>
      <form onSubmit={addContact}>
        <div>
          name: <input 
                  value={newName}
                  onChange={handleNameChange}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          number: <input
                  value={newNumber}
                  onChange={handleNumberChange}/>
          </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <h2>Numbers</h2>
      <ul>
          <Person persons={persons} searchTerm={searchTerm} /> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Person.js

```
const Person = ({ persons, searchTerm }) => {
  return persons
    .filter((person) => person.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm))
    .map((person) => (
    <li key={person.id}>
      {person.name}: <span>{person.number}</span>
    </li>
  ));
};

export default Person;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-architecture-iu8qkz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It works just fine <3 Thank you so much